# Difficulty in replicating Screen layout issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I have a settings tab page in my application. It works perfectly for all users, except one with HTC WildFire phone.

I have implemented all good practices suggested by Android to have multiple assets for different screen sizes and screen densities.

But still for this user, when he opens Settings tab page, the tab takes most the screen with a big box and very less space left for actual settings to appear at the bottom.

I don't have a HTC Wildfire phone. Is there a way, I can create emulator that would match exactly to HTC Wildfire screen and replicate this issue ?

Expert opinions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Namely that device was our worst case platform.  No matter what we tried, we couldn't overcome some of its quirks.  I remember weird ListView separators, borders around images - and there was something else as well.

So it may be just the device.  But we also did manage to adjust a lot on an emulator with the corresponding (low) resolution.  Yes, you should create one.